# Which way will get high performance while selecting many data IQueryable Vs For loop (Using Entity Frame Work)

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get a list from the database containing two or more lists inside that list.(using .net core, entity framework).Assume I have two table call header and details table.

Header Table 
[image: Header Table]

Detail Table 
[image: Detail Table]

And I want the result like this:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "Country":"Singapore",
         "Hospital_List":[
            {
               "Hospital_Name":"SG Host A"
            },
            {
               "Hospital_Name":"SG Host A"
            }
         ]
      },
      {

      }
   ]
}
```

I only know two ways to get the result like this,First Way, select Country list data with blank Hospital list as **List**,then for loop that list to select related Hospital list from db again.
And Second Way,select  Country list data with blank Hospital list as **IQueryable List**,and then select related Hospital list via jointing with Hospital Table.So my question is

> Which way should i used to get higher performance? And Is any other way?

Please remember there has a lot of field and data in my real table.

Comment: *And Is any other way?* -- Yes, `Include`. Only you can test which way is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loop give give you the lowest perfomance, because you will create SQL query for each iteration. Instead of this, try following solution:

```
from hospital in hospitals
group hospital by hospital.CID into gh
join country in countries
  on gh.FirstOrDefault().CID equals country.CID
select new
{
  Country = country.Country,
  Hospital_List = from h in gh select h
}
```

**EDITED:**

And if your model created right you can use this code:

```
from hospital in hospitals
        join country in countries
           on hospital.Country equals country
        group hospital by hospital.CID into gh
        select new
        {
            Country = from h in gh select h.Country.Country,
            Hospital_List = from h in gh select h
        }
```